# Actionscript 3 addChild Issue

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, addchild

This is a test for a XML image menu. In the code I create my containers, I have a movie clip in the stage (`menu_mc`).

**CODE:**

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.text.TLFTextField;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.TextLayoutFormat;
import flashx.textLayout.elements.TextFlow;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.TextAlign;
import flash.display.Sprite;

var title_mc:TLFTextField;
var img_mc:MovieClip;
var bg_mc:MovieClip;
var myFormat:TextLayoutFormat;
var myTextFlow:TextFlow;

createContainers();

function createContainers():void {

//CREATE IMAGE CONTAINER
img_mc = new MovieClip();
menu_mc.addChild(img_mc);
img_mc.x = -50;
img_mc.y = -60,10;

//CREATE TEXTFIELD
title_mc = new TLFTextField();
addChild(title_mc);
title_mc.x = 0;
title_mc.y = 20;
title_mc.width = 120;
title_mc.height = 50,70;
title_mc.multiline = true;
title_mc.embedFonts = true;
title_mc.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
title_mc.wordWrap = true;
title_mc.text = "text text text text text text text";

myFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();
myFormat.textIndent = 0;
myFormat.color = 0x0000FF;
myFormat.fontFamily = "Arial";
myFormat.fontSize = 20;
myFormat.textAlign = TextAlign.CENTER;
myFormat.textAlignLast = TextAlign.CENTER;

myTextFlow = title_mc.textFlow;
myTextFlow.hostFormat = myFormat;
myTextFlow.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();

//CREATE BACKGROUND CONTAINER
bg_mc = new MovieClip();
menu_mc.addChild(bg_mc);
bg_mc.x = 0;
bg_mc.y = 70;
bg_mc.width = 120;
bg_mc.height = 50;

//CRETAE SPRITE
var square:Sprite = new Sprite();
square.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x000000);
square.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
square.graphics.drawRect(0,0,300,300);
square.graphics.endFill();
menu_mc.addChild(square);

}
```

My problem is I want that, for example, `bg_mc` inside `menu_mc` and `square` inside `bg_mc`.

If I try, for example:

```
menu_mc.bg_mc.addChild(square); //error
```

or

```
menu_mc.addChild(title_mc);  //textfield disapears
```

Flash give me this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `bg_mc` inside `menu_mc` do : `menu_mc.addChild(bg_mc)` ,
and then  `square` inside `bg_mc` do : `bg_mc.addChild(square)`.

`menu_mc.bg_mc.addChild(square);` will give you an error because in the `MovieClip` `menu_mc` there is no property named `bg_mc`. adding a child XYZ don't imply the creation of a property named XYZ.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the explanation. The errors disapears, I don't understand one more thing, why my square disapears if I put them inside a movie clip bg_mc.addChild(square);